# Black screen at final step of Ubuntu 14.04.05 installation

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, live-usb

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 14.04.05 via USB selecting "erase disk" menu entry, in a Asus UN42, everything is fine except for the final step, when asked to reboot the system at "installation complete" popup. Clicking "Restart Now" the screen goes black and nothing happens. After a manual reboot (disconnect cable), everythinh seems to work fine, is there anything to worry about?

**EDIT**

This happened twice yesterday, today I tried again waiting some minute before pressing "restart now" and everything went as expected, asking me to remove the USB media and press enter.. still confused!